# Schrödinger equation and $\rm U(1)$ group

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, schroedinger-equation, group-theory, gauge-invariance

I watched two youtube videos: https://youtu.be/paQLJKtiAEE and https://youtu.be/V5kgruUjVBs. Now, I compared those two videos. One talk about the breaking of the Schrödinger equation after applying local phase transformations, and the other talks about the Lagrangian. My question is, is it right to talk about the breaking in the Schrödinger equation, the same way as the symmetry breaking in the Lagrangian, by applying a $\rm U(1)$ group? So can you apply $\rm U(1)$ to the Schrödinger equation, and say that is the local phase transformation?

I am sorry if this an easy question. For background information: I am a first year student doing a project about quantum field theory for a video.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to make the link more apparent, you can have a Lagrangian point of view for the Schrödinger equation. The free equation can be derived from the Lagrangian density:
$$
\mathcal L = \frac{1}{2i}(\psi \partial_t\psi^*-\psi^*\partial_t\psi)-\frac{1}{2m}(\nabla \psi^*)\cdot(\nabla \psi)
$$
Note that physically, $\psi$ does not represent a particle's wave function, but rather a (complex scalar) field that will eventually need to be quantised (second quantisation). It can be derived by taking the non-relativisitic regime of the Klein Gordon Lagrangian.

Similarly, the Lagrangian has a global $U(1)$ symmetry. By introducing gauge fields $V,A$ and replacing the derivatives to covariant ones:
$$
i\partial_t\to i\partial_t-qV \\
-i\nabla \to -i\nabla -qA\\
$$
and defining the gauge transformations:
$$
\psi\to e^{i\theta}\psi \\
V \to V -\frac{1}{q}\partial_t\theta \\
A \to A+\frac{1}{q}\nabla\theta
$$
your new Lagrangian exhibits gauge invariance.

Btw, if you look closely at PBS's video, it is not exactly the usual spineless Schrödinger equation that is granted gauge invariance, but rather the spin $1/2$ counterpart, hence the Pauli matrix at the beginning. The same reasoning works though.

Conversely, for QED, you could have started from the free Dirac equation:
$$
(i\not \partial -m)\psi=0
$$
and imposed gauge invariance on it by introducing the gauge fields in a similar fashion. however, thinking in terms of Lagrangians is more convenient. Fr example, it's just a scalar so you have less equations to handle, and helps exhibit Noether currents more easily.

Hope this helps.